# Unable to run python graphics in cygwin

Tags: python, graphics, cygwin, x11, xserver

I tried to do:

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin()

pt = Point(100, 50)
pt.draw(win)

cir = Circle(pt, 25)
cir.draw(win)

cir.setOutline('red')
cir.setFill('blue')
```

However, no matter what installation on cygwin I tried from the net, it gave:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "observe.py", line 2, in <module>
    from graphics import *
  File "/home/user/graphics.py", line 164, in <module>
    _root = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1814, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

It seems to have different behavior when I move to Ubuntu or Mac.

Comment: If someone looks at this in the future, it might be helpful to add "cygwin" to the title?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your X server is running?

This should be done

> [...] by using the "XWin Server" shortcut under "Cygwin-X" on
> the Start Menu

...according to http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html